# Full height display:table-cell content without making parent 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get content inside a `table-cell` div to reach 100% of the parent div. However I can only achieve this by adding  `height:100%;` to the `display:table` parent div.

This would normally be fine but because I need to have html,body {
height:100%;} for full height content elsewhere on the website this makes the table full height of the browser, which I do not want.

Is there a way I can make the content within my `table-cell` full height without having to put `height:100;` on the `display:table;` div?

**[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1bdyuwsf/18/)**

```css
html,
body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#banner {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.o-ds-table {
 position:relative;
 display:table;  
 width:100%;
  /* height:100%; this fixed the red content being full height but makes the table full height of content*/
 margin:0 auto;
}

.o-ds-table-cell {
 display:table-cell;
 padding:0 10px;
 position:relative;
  border:2px solid blue;
  background:yellow;
}

.cell-item-width-4 {
  width:25%;
}

.panel-item {
 background:red;
 height:100%;
 display:block;

}

p {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
 SCROLL DOWN!
</section>

<div class="o-ds-table">
                        
  <div class="o-ds-table-cell cell-item-width-4 panel-wrap">
    <div class="panel-item">

     <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec massa tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec massa tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec massa tortor.
     </p>

    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="o-ds-table-cell cell-item-width-4> panel-wrap">
    <div class="panel-item">

     <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.
     </p>

    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="o-ds-table-cell cell-item-width-4 panel-wrap">
    <div class="panel-item">

     <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. 
     </p>

    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="o-ds-table-cell cell-item-width-4 panel-wrap">
    <div class="panel-item">

     <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. 
     </p>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<section>
  stuff sits below 
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam mollis ultrices placerat. Duis at bibendum urna. Vestibulum augue ex, lacinia vitae orci consectetur, elementum congue neque. Proin sed rhoncus felis. Donec justo arcu, iaculis eget sollicitudin sed, posuere nec mi. Cras sed ligula vel eros tincidunt interdum ac sit amet sapien. Curabitur rutrum felis id neque convallis iaculis. Sed viverra in magna sed mollis. Sed ac iaculis metus, vel pretium purus. Maecenas accumsan in ligula a vehicula. In sit amet tortor mi.

Cras pellentesque tempor ex id gravida. Pellentesque gravida ipsum eget dignissim ullamcorper. Nulla sagittis nibh et tortor tempor, quis pellentesque ligula tincidunt. Vivamus feugiat risus erat, ut efficitur nisi malesuada commodo. Suspendisse feugiat consequat massa at luctus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent ut purus et neque interdum mollis. Nulla interdum finibus lorem vitae laoreet. Duis accumsan dictum placerat. Cras et laoreet justo. Donec aliquet mattis eros ut placerat. Sed quis viverra diam.
  
</section>
```

Comment: and what is the purpose? the content is text so making the height 100% will simply stretch the background to the bottom,

Comment: Yes I need to make the red background stretch the bottom of the yellow to match a design doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you to look up `flexbox css` this is a great way to make 2D layouts.

Because your using `div`'s instead of a real `<table></table>` I'm assuming (correct me if i'm wrong) your using this way to form a layout from table css property's.

```css
html,
body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#banner {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.o-ds-table {

    position:relative;
    display:flex; /* I changed this */ 
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.o-ds-table-cell {
    /* display:table-cell; not needed with flex */
    padding:0 10px;
    flex: 1; /* I changed this */
    /* position:relative;  not needed with flex */
  border:2px solid blue;
  background:yellow;
}

.cell-item-width-4 {
  /* width:25%;  not needed with flex */
}

.panel-item {
    background:red;
    height:100%;
    /* display:block;  not needed with flex */

}

p {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
 SCROLL DOWN!
</section>

<div class="o-ds-table">

  <div class="o-ds-table-cell cell-item-width-4 panel-wrap">
    <div class="panel-item">

     <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec massa tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec massa tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec massa tortor.
     </p>

    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="o-ds-table-cell cell-item-width-4> panel-wrap">
    <div class="panel-item">

     <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.
     </p>

    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="o-ds-table-cell cell-item-width-4 panel-wrap">
    <div class="panel-item">

     <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. 
     </p>

    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="o-ds-table-cell cell-item-width-4 panel-wrap">
    <div class="panel-item">

     <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. 
     </p>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<section>
  stuff sits below 

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam mollis ultrices placerat. Duis at bibendum urna. Vestibulum augue ex, lacinia vitae orci consectetur, elementum congue neque. Proin sed rhoncus felis. Donec justo arcu, iaculis eget sollicitudin sed, posuere nec mi. Cras sed ligula vel eros tincidunt interdum ac sit amet sapien. Curabitur rutrum felis id neque convallis iaculis. Sed viverra in magna sed mollis. Sed ac iaculis metus, vel pretium purus. Maecenas accumsan in ligula a vehicula. In sit amet tortor mi.

Cras pellentesque tempor ex id gravida. Pellentesque gravida ipsum eget dignissim ullamcorper. Nulla sagittis nibh et tortor tempor, quis pellentesque ligula tincidunt. Vivamus feugiat risus erat, ut efficitur nisi malesuada commodo. Suspendisse feugiat consequat massa at luctus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent ut purus et neque interdum mollis. Nulla interdum finibus lorem vitae laoreet. Duis accumsan dictum placerat. Cras et laoreet justo. Donec aliquet mattis eros ut placerat. Sed quis viverra diam.

</section>
```

Some extra information: https://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html

Comment: this won't work within Safari ... Actually you didn't really use flexbox for the height issue, but you relied on a particular case within flexbox which is the stretch effect that make the height:100% work in this particular case. Change the alignment and you will notice this

Comment: @TemaniAfif can't guaranty full browser support for all answers, although I appreciate the warning. I will test it more. Could you be more clear on the "didn't really use flexbox" part? I'm not getting what your trying to say.

Comment: change the alignment, for example use `align-items:flex-start` or anything else o the parent element and you will see the behavior ... you won't have 100% height, you only have it if you keep the default alignment which is stretch and this alignment allow you to use the height:100% inside it [which is something that may not behave like expected]

Comment: to make it short, this is valid but you are relying on something that is not under official specification but it works in mordern browsers and I also use it by the way

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ah, ok understood. Your right. It needs some more love and better implication. Thanks for the recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the background to be stretched then you can simply consider multiple background within the `table-cell`:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.o-ds-table {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  /* height:100%; this fixed the red content being full height but makes the table full height of content*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.o-ds-table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red, red) center/calc(100% - 20px) 100% no-repeat, 
    yellow;
}

.cell-item-width-4 {
  width: 25%;
}

.panel-item {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
  SCROLL DOWN!
</section>

<div class="o-ds-table">

  <div class="o-ds-table-cell cell-item-width-4 panel-wrap">
    <div class="panel-item">

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec massa tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec massa tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec massa tortor.
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="o-ds-table-cell cell-item-width-4> panel-wrap">
    <div class="panel-item">

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="o-ds-table-cell cell-item-width-4 panel-wrap">
    <div class="panel-item">

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="o-ds-table-cell cell-item-width-4 panel-wrap">
    <div class="panel-item">

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<section>
  stuff sits below Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam mollis ultrices placerat. Duis at bibendum urna. Vestibulum augue ex, lacinia vitae orci consectetur, elementum congue neque. Proin sed rhoncus felis. Donec justo arcu, iaculis
  eget sollicitudin sed, posuere nec mi. Cras sed ligula vel eros tincidunt interdum ac sit amet sapien. Curabitur rutrum felis id neque convallis iaculis. Sed viverra in magna sed mollis. Sed ac iaculis metus, vel pretium purus. Maecenas accumsan in
  ligula a vehicula. In sit amet tortor mi. Cras pellentesque tempor ex id gravida. Pellentesque gravida ipsum eget dignissim ullamcorper. Nulla sagittis nibh et tortor tempor, quis pellentesque ligula tincidunt. Vivamus feugiat risus erat, ut efficitur
  nisi malesuada commodo. Suspendisse feugiat consequat massa at luctus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent ut purus et neque interdum mollis. Nulla interdum finibus lorem vitae laoreet.
  Duis accumsan dictum placerat. Cras et laoreet justo. Donec aliquet mattis eros ut placerat. Sed quis viverra diam.

</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `class="o-ds-table-cell"` divisions are already reaching 100% of the parent division.

Note that in the HTML snippet that you provided, that parent division (`class="o-ds-table"`) has NOTHING other than its own children to determine what height it will be - so it becomes the height of the child that has the maximum height.

If you provide something else that determines the height of the "o-ds-table" division, your table-cell divisions will stretch to match it, exactly as you want it. I cannot tell you how to change that height so it isn't controlled solely by the child elements as it is right now. It depends on what that division is for and how you plan to place it in relation to other content. In most cases, you would want to place it inside some container that holds it as well as neighboring content and set widths and heights proportionally or using fixed sizes, as your layout requires.

It may be a good idea to add 'min-height' as well, if there is nothing else to prevent the height from becoming too small.

Comment: it's about the content *within* the table-cell not the table-cell which is by default 100% height because it's a table layout